# How to show the video with mediapipe in html in django?

Tags: python, django, file-upload, mp4, mediapipe

my html and views.py are refer to https://roytuts.com/upload-and-play-video-using-django/,
but i want to change the display video to video with mediapipe,what should i do or change in my code?

mediapipe code in views.py:

```
def process_video(filename):
  input_video_path = filename
  output_video_path = f"processed_{filename}"

  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_video_path)
  width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
  height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
  fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')
  out = cv2.VideoWriter(output_video_path, fourcc, 20.0, (width, height))

  while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = holistic.process(image)

    # Draw landmarks and connections
    mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.left_hand_landmarks, mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS,
                mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(121, 22, 76), thickness=2, circle_radius=4),
                mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(121, 44, 250), thickness=2, circle_radius=2))

    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.right_hand_landmarks, mp_holistic.HAND_CONNECTIONS,
                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80, 22, 10), thickness=2, circle_radius=4),
                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(80, 44, 121), thickness=2, circle_radius=2))

    mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.pose_landmarks, mp_holistic.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245, 117, 66), thickness=2, circle_radius=4),
                 mp_drawing.DrawingSpec(color=(245, 66, 230), thickness=2, circle_radius=2))

    out.write(image)


cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```